Changing pipeline lookup output value tag to something else
New on here but also fairly new to Azure ADF so apologies in advance!
I am currently involved in migrating from one ETL toolset to Azure ADF and the first batch is essentially looking like:
1> Lookup via a SQL query (Sql Server table)
2> @activity('lookupsql').output to feed into a Web service
The lookup works fine, and hard-coding the body in the Web works fine but to make the body automated - ie using the @activity('lookupsql').output to the be body for the Web part is failing.
The reason of failure is the way the @activity('lookupsql').output is structured.
Expected input for the Web API target is:
{ "items": [ { "name": "name1", "code": "code1" }, { "name": "name2", "code": "code2" } ] }
However @activity('lookupsql').output outputs it as "value" and not "items"
Is there

A way to replace value with items?
Am I working with this in the correct manner?

Note, some SQL table results will be in the thousands and others could be under 10.
Thanks in advance!
If I copy the output from @activity('lookupsql').output in debug mode and hard-code it in the body of the Web API part, it works fine...as long as I replace the value to items.

Lookup Output by default come as value  to add the Items  in place of value you need to use dynamic expression.
You can use this expression where we are adding items in place of value and converting it to Json format.
@json(concat('{ "items": ',activity('Lookup1').output.value,'}'))


You can see below input body for web api in appropriate format.

